# Couchbase: How does USE KEYS process the retrieval of data?

Tags: couchbase

Does it process it in a parallel manner? Does it ensure ordering?

I need to retrieve a group of documents that have no ordering besides the order I put them in the USE KEYS clause.

So if I do a USE KEYS [a, b, c], I expect [a, b, c]. Should I expect this behavior?